# What does WhatsApp Web's "?debug=true" do?

Tags: whatsapp

Just randomly noticed it, you can see it in
[https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Awhatsapp.com+"%3Fdebug%3Dtrue"](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Awhatsapp.com+%22%3Fdebug%3Dtrue%22)

[image: WhatsApp Web's "?debug=true"]